# For what values of p does this series converge

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$\sum_{k=1}^∞\frac{k}{\sqrt{4+k^p}}$$

I've already tried the integral test but failed to find a primitive, and also check if $$\lim_{n\to∞}an=0$$ 
But not totally satisfied with the result

Comment: Did you type $x^{p}$ for $k^{p}$?.

Comment: Yes, my mistake, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The series $\sum\limits^{\infty}_{k=1}\frac{1}{k^{s}}$ converges if and only if $s>1$.

In your case note that $4+k^{p} > k^{p}$, so since $\sqrt{}:[0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ is monotonic also
$$ \sum\limits^{\infty}_{k=1}\frac{k}{\sqrt{4+k^p}} \leq \sum\limits^{\infty}_{k=1}\frac{k}{\sqrt{k^{p}}} = \sum\limits^{\infty}_{k=1}k^{1-\frac{p}{2}}. $$
Therefore the series converges iff $\frac{p}{2}-1>1$, so if and only if $p>4$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $p >0$. $\frac 1 {\sqrt 2  k^{p/2 -1}} \leq  \frac k  {\sqrt {4+ k^p}} \leq \frac 1 { k^{p/2 -1}}$ for $k$ sufficiently large. Comparing with $\sum \frac 1 { k^{p/2 -1}}$ we see that the series converges iff $p >4$. I leave the case $p \leq 0$ to you.